# CSS3: How to remove white border around flex-container?

Tags: css, flexbox

Following the example on w3schools for flex-container, there is following example: 
http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_flexline

```css
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.flex-item {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div>
</div>
```

I've attached the result as an image. The image shows a white border between browser edge and flex-container.

How can I remove the white border?

[image: flex-container with white border around]

Comment: That's not a white border, it's just the HTML body.  Your flex container is not the full width.

Comment: By default, user agent stylesheets apply a `margin` to the `body` element, usually `8px`. You can remove this by using `body { margin: 0; }`.

Comment: @Ricky : Great! - I've added `body { margin: 0; }` into the top of CSS-File and the white "border" disappeared. I didn't know that the default user agent stylesheet is 8px. I would like to rate your answer as helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The border you are seeing is the html default browser margin. It's a good practice to reset all margin and padding elements:

```
* { //* is known by wildcard, it selects all elements on the DOM
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

And please always avoid `!important` on your css, that's a really bad practice and it makes harder to reuse/maintain your code.

Answer (score 1):

In case the issue is due to the lack of browser reset on the body, I usually add the following to my sites/applications:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        }
```

JSFiddle of the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/j66gcfcj/

As a part of your browser resets, you can use:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

The above would easily fix your issue, but would affect everything in your site. I typically use the above wildcard to actually apply `box-sizing: border-box;` as in:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

In case you don't want to affect the site you've already been working on and want to focus strictly on the flex container, then use the following:

```
.flex-container {
    margin: 0;
    }
```

You can also do a wildcard selection on everything inside your flex container:

```
.flex-container * {
    margin: 0;
    }
```

And say that you want to apply `margin: 0` to both your flex container as well as everything inside it:

```
.flex-container,
.flex-container * {
    margin: 0;
    }
```

You can learn more about browser resets by going to:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add css rules for the container:

```
.flex-container {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Or make your flex container full width. For example like this:

```
min-width: 100vw;
```

And it's a good practice to reset all `paddings` and `margins` at the top of your CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

This will prevent the occurrence of problems such as this

Comment: You misspelled _padding_